# How to load an image over an accordion

Tags: jquery, css, image, wordpress

I want to create the following effect:
A page loads with a jqueryUI accordion. Above the accordion (in theory a higher z index) an image is loaded. The image is the first thing the viewer sees. When the image is clicked it "explodes" using jquery effects revealing the accordion. In essence I have this working but I'm looking for a better solution for loading the image on the page. At present the only way I can get this to work is using the following structure:

```
<div id="image container">//Positioned "relative" in the css
  <div id="image"></div>//The image is added as a background in the css, positioned as "absolute"
  <div id="accordion">
  .
  .
  .
 </div>//End accordion
</div>// End Image Container
```

If I attempt to put the image as an element('<'img'>') inside the div#image then the image always appears below the accordion (in the z dimension). 
I've tried elevating the z-index on the div#image and the <'img> but the image still appears below the accordion.

I would like to be able to control the position of the image within the '<'div#image'>' to enhance the exploding effect so I think it would give me more flexibility if I could load the '<'img'>' in the  instead of using it as a background for the '<'div'>'.

Note: This is happening on a Wordpress page but I don't believe that has any bearing on the issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not have the accordion invisible until after the jquery "explode" event?

Comment: Controlling the position of the image should be simple enough as long as you put it inside the panel `<div>` and use relative positioning. I agree with Javalsu about the invisibility of the ui.panel until after the image is exploded. Even invisible, it should still take up the space intended and give you the ability to place the image.

Comment: @DevlshOne: Thanks for your response. If I place the image using an <img> tag inside <div id="image container"> then it always appears below the accordion. Even elevating the z index to some ridiculously high number doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Javalsu:  Thanks that lead me to a much better solution.